# Google Cloud logging, Python3.8 standard environment, group request related logs by trace id

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-logging

I stucked with problem during Google Cloud Logging setup for Python3.8 in Google App Engine Standard environment.
I'm using FastAPI with unicorn. My code logging configuration:

```
import logging.config
import sys

from google.cloud import logging as google_logging

from app.settings import ENV, _settings


if _settings.ENV == ENV.LOCAL:
    MAIN_LOGGER = 'console'
    LOGGER_CONF_DICT = {
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'verbose',
        'stream': sys.stdout,
        'level': _settings.LOG_LEVEL.upper(),
    }
else:
    log_client = google_logging.Client()
    MAIN_LOGGER = 'stackdriver_logging'
    LOGGER_CONF_DICT = {
        'class': 'app.gcloud_logs.GCLHandler',
        'client': log_client,
        'name': 'appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log'
        # I've tried other names: stdout, %2FA instead of / symbol, appengine.googleapis.com/stdout
        # the same result or no logs at all
    }

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(log_color)s%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)',
            '()': 'colorlog.ColoredFormatter',
            'log_colors': {
                'DEBUG': 'cyan',
                'INFO': 'green',
                'WARNING': 'yellow',
                'ERROR': 'red',
                'CRITICAL': 'bold_red',
            },
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        MAIN_LOGGER: {**LOGGER_CONF_DICT},
        'blackhole': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.NullHandler'},
    },
    'loggers': {
        'fastapi': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': [MAIN_LOGGER]},
        'uvicorn.error': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': [MAIN_LOGGER], 'propagate': False},
        'uvicorn.access': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': [MAIN_LOGGER], 'propagate': False},
        'uvicorn': {'level': 'INFO', 'handlers': [MAIN_LOGGER], 'propagate': False},
        'google.cloud.logging.handlers.transports.background_thread': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'handlers': ['blackhole'],
                                                                       'propagate': False},
        '': {
            'level': _settings.LOG_LEVEL.upper(),
            'handlers': [MAIN_LOGGER],
            'propagate': True,
        },

    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
```

And my logging handler code:

```
import os
from typing import Any, Dict, Optional

from google.cloud.logging.handlers import CloudLoggingHandler
from google.cloud.logging.resource import Resource
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette_context import context

from app.settings import _settings


class GCLHandler(CloudLoggingHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        message = super(GCLHandler, self).format(record)
        request: Optional[Request] = None
        trace: Optional[str] = None
        span_id: Optional[str] = None
        user_id: Optional[int] = None
        resource = Resource(
            type='gae_app',
            labels={
                'module_id': os.environ['GAE_SERVICE'],
                'project_id': _settings.PROJECT_NAME,
                'version_id': os.environ['GAE_VERSION'],
                'zone': 'us16'  # tried without zone - the same result
            }
        )

        labels: Dict[str, Any] = {}

        if context.exists():  # I'm sure that it works
            request = context.get('request')  # I'm sure that it works
            user_id = context.get('user_id')  # I'm sure that it works

        if user_id is not None:
            labels['user_id'] = user_id

        if request:
            if request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context'):
                cloud_trace = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context').split('/')
                if len(cloud_trace) > 1:
                    span_id = cloud_trace[1].split(';')[0]

                trace = f'projects/{_settings.PROJECT_NAME}/traces/{cloud_trace[0]}'
                labels['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = cloud_trace[0]  # Found in some guides, not sure that its neccessary
                labels['appengine.googleapis.com/trace_id'] = cloud_trace[0]  # Found in some guides, not sure that its neccessary

        self.transport.send(
            record,
            message,
            resource=resource,
            labels=labels,
            trace=trace,
            span_id=span_id
        )
```

I've got some strange results in logs viewer that my log has the same trace as request log, but they're not grouped [image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
log_client = google_logging.Client()
MAIN_LOGGER = 'stackdriver_logging'
LOGGER_CONF_DICT = {
    'class': 'app.gcloud_logs.GCLHandler',
    'client': log_client,
    'name': 'app'
}
```

Change name to `app` is helped

Comment: What is the request log's severity (log level)? Is it 'any' or is it based on the log severity of child (nested) logs?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of logs in [**App Engine**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs) :

- Request log: A log of the requests that are sent to your app. App Engine automatically creates entries in the request log.
- App log: log entries that you write to a supported framework or file as described on this page.

The both logs are send to the **Cloud Logging Agent** automatically by App Engine Standard.

On first request, app logs and request logs are not correlated and that's why there are not shown in a group , this is a [**known issue stated in App Engine Official Documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs#known_issues). However in the second request, you can see that the logs are shown in a group.

A feature request in [Public Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/138365527) has already been created for this behavior where you will get all the updates regarding the fix.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to set the severity of the request log? I'm able to group them using trace, but the severity of the request log is always 'Any', its supposed to be equal to the highest severity level of child (nested) logs